# Linq Fuzzy Search

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, linq, search

I am filtering results from the database based on the Pickup Location & Drop Location.

**My Database contains values like:**

> Pickup Location: San Jose 95002, San Jose 95112, San Jose 95119, etc.
>
> Drop Location: SFO, SJC, Castro Valley

**My search strings are:**

> Pickup Search String: 195, San Jose, California, 95119
>
> Drop Search String: 56, Castro Valley Boulevard, Castro Valley, California

I am splitting the search string and looking for the best match using "Contains" in my Linq Query, but to improve the time, I break the loop as soon as a match is found, which returns undesirable results, is there a better way to do this?

**Pickup Address:** 195|San Jose|California|95119

**Destination Address:** 56|Castro Valley Boulevard|Castro Valley|California

```
            String startLocation = PickupAddress.Replace("\"", "").Replace("/", "");
            string[] locationList = startLocation.Split('|');
            var rateData = new Rate();
            foreach (var location in locationList)
            {
                String startLocationData = location.Trim();
                rateData = (from p in _context.Rates
                            where (p.StartLocation.Contains(startLocationData) 
                            && p.EndLocation.Contains(DestinationAddress))
                            && p.VehicleCategoryID == VehicleID
                            select p).FirstOrDefault();
                if (rateData != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }


            if (rateData != null)
            {
                String amount = Convert.ToString(rateData.Amount).Replace('$', ' ');
                String plusRate = Convert.ToString(rateData.PlusRate).Replace('$', ' ');
                String fee = Convert.ToString(rateData.QwykrFee).Replace('$', ' ');
                Decimal retVal = Convert.ToDecimal(amount) + Convert.ToDecimal(plusRate) + Convert.ToDecimal(fee);
                return retVal;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/fuzzy

https://github.com/DanHarltey/Fastenshtein

The fastest .Net Levenshtein around.

Fastenshtein is an optimized and unit tested Levenshtein implementation. It is optimized for speed and memory usage.

From the included brenchmarking tests comparing random words of 3 to 20 random chars to other Nuget Levenshtein implementations.